# python optimising multiple functions with common variables

Tags: scipy, mathematical-optimization, minimization

i am trying to minimize (globally) 3 functions that use common variables, i tried to combine them into one function and minimize that using `L-BFGS-B`(i need to set boundaries for the variables), but it has shown to be very difficult to balance each parameter with weightings, i.e. when one is minimised the other will not be. I also tried to use `SLSQP` method to minimize one of them while setting others as constraints, but the constraints are often ignored/not met.
Here are what need to be minimized, all the maths are done in `meritscalculation` and `meritoflength`, `meritofROC`, `meritofproximity`, `heightorderreturned`are returned from the calculations as globals.

```
def lengthmerit(x0):
    meritscalculation(x0)  
    print meritoflength
    return meritoflength

def ROCmerit(x0):
    meritscalculation(x0)
    print meritofROC
    return meritofROC

def proximitymerit(x0):
    meritscalculation(x0)
    print  meritofproximity+heightorder
    return meritofproximity+heightorder
```

i want to minimize all of them using a common x0 (with boundaries) as independent variable, is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want to do ?

```
minimize a * amerit(x) + b * bmerit(x) + c * cmerit(x)
over a, b, c, x:
    a + b + c = 1
    a >= 0.1, b >= 0.1, c >= 0.1 (say)
    x in xbounds
```

If `x` is say `[x0 x1 .. x9]`, set up a new variable `abcx = [a b c x0 x1 .. x9]`,
constrain `a + b + c = 1` with a penalty term added to the objective function,
and minimize this:

```
define fabc( abcx ):
    """ abcx = a, b, c, x
        -> a * amerit(x) + ... + penalty 100 (a + b + c - 1)^2 
    """ 
    a, b, c, x = abcx[0], abcx[1], abcx[2], abcx[3:]  # split
    fa = a * amerit(x)
    fb = b * bmerit(x)
    fc = c * cmerit(x) 
    penalty = 100 * (a + b + c - 1) ** 2  # 100 ?
    f = fa + fb + fc + penalty
    print "fabc: %6.2g = %6.2g + %6.2g + %6.2g + %6.2g   a b c: %6.2g %6.2g %6.2g" % (
                f, fa, fb, fc, penalty, a, b, c )
    return f
```

and `bounds = [[0.1, 0.5]] * 3 + xbounds`, i.e. each of `a b c in 0.1 .. 0.5` or so.
The long `print` s should show you *why* one of `a b c` approach 0 --
maybe one of `amerit() bmerit() cmerit()` is way bigger than the others ?
`Plot`s instead of `print`s would be easy too.

Summary:
1) formulate the  problem clearly on paper, as at the top
2) translate that into python.

Comment: yes that is what i wanted to do, so this is basically including the weightings into the optimisation process and letting the computer to balance it, right? And also there is a big difference between each `merit()` function (order of 1000 roughly), how does this affect the bounds for a, b, c? will it still be `[0.1, inf]` or something else ? Anyway, I am testing this method now, thank you very much for your effort, you have been most helpful

Answer (score 0):

here is the result of some scaling and weighting

objective function:

```
merit_function=wa*meritoflength*1e3+wb*meritofROC+wc*meritofproximity+wd*heightorder*10+1000 * (wa+wb+wc+wd-1) ** 2
```

input:

```
abcdex=np.array(( 0.5, 0.5, 0.1, 0.3, 0.1...))
```

output:

```
fun: array([ 7.79494644])

   x: array([  4.00000000e-01,   2.50000000e-01,   1.00000000e-01,
     2.50000000e-01...])


meritoflength : 0.00465499380753.  #target 1e-5, usually start at 0.1
meritofROC: 23.7317956542          #target ~1,  range <33
Heightorder: 0                     #target :strictly 0, range <28
meritofproximity : 0.0             #target:less than 0.02,   range <0.052
```

i realised after a few runs, all the weightings tend to stay at the minimum values of the bound, and im back to manually tuning the scaling problem i started with.

Is there a possibility that my optimisation function isnt finding the true global minimum?

here is how i minimised it:

```
minimizer_kwargs = {"method": "L-BFGS-B", "bounds": bnds, "tol":1e0 }

ret = basinhopping(merit_function, abcdex, minimizer_kwargs=minimizer_kwargs, niter=10)
zoom = ret['x']

res = minimize(merit_function, zoom, method = 'L-BFGS-B', bounds=bnds, tol=1e-6)
```

Comment: `tol = 1` ?? try 1e-4. Read the [basinhopping doc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.basinhopping.html) carefully: "For best results `T` should be comparable to the separation (in function value) between local minima" -- it may be sensitive to x0, stepsize ... too. And "weightings tend to stay at the minimum values of the bound": they must sum to 1 ? else increase the penalty factor 100.

Comment: the reason i set tol=1 is to scan a bigger domain with lower precision(or it'll waste a lot of time trying to minimize a large value), then i used a second `minimize` function to improve the minimum value returned by the first minimisation to a higher accuracy

Comment: You can't expect a good minimum in near-0 run time, on a high-dimensional problem, with a tool with unknown parameters. I'd suggest starting with a tiny problem where you know an answer, to get some experience on the function value / runtime tradeoff.